# Break out or bypass php functions

Tags: php, ctf

I'm currently doing an online CTF and I have LFI an can read the source code of the upload function. In there I see the following line:

```
shell_exec('rm -rf ' . directory/ . '*.p*');
```

So anytime I upload a .php file, it gets deleted.

Is there a way to break out the code so the remove of `*.p*` file never happens or can I execute .php files without having the file extension being .php?

Comment: It's a stretch but try using `.php` as the filename. It definitely won't get deleted, but it may not execute either

Comment: Or play "stupid". The PHP files are only removed after the zip unzips and is deleted. Try making a PHP file "first" and then add 10,000 blank files. You only need the process to take a few seconds - while the zip unloads everything else your PHP file is sitting in the uploads directory and can be executed. Not sure if there is an easier way to make a slowly extracting zip file....

Comment: Have you try .shtml extention ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution: upload the file as hidden, for example: .shell.php and call the file directly.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the PHP file in a subdirectory and then zip it *with* the sub directory, so that when the zip is unpacked it would end up somewhere like:

```
uploads/sub/file.php
```

This won't match the delete command.  Presumably you will still be able to run the PHP file in a sub directory.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, no luck.. when I do that, the upload doens't seem to succeed.

Comment: I added some more info regarding the upload php file.

Comment: @Nerotix the `-j` flag on the unzip causes it to throw away the directory inside the zip file, so this doesn't work.

Comment: I figured it out with some help from a friend. The solution is the make the make the php file hidden, for example: .shell.php since it only checks the first period. Thanks for trying to help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the web server is and the PHP config, but you might be able to use a .htaccess or .user.ini from my htshells project to bypass the rm command. https://github.com/wireghoul/htshells

Also, a quick side bar, **LFI vulnerabilities execute PHP code**, if it's reading code then it's a different class of vulnerability, such as arbitrary file read, directory traversal, etc. If it's an actual LFI, then you can just slip an `exit` at the end of your included code to halt execution before it reaches the rm.